# Other Way to Express an Exponential Function

Tags: exponential-function

When you have an exponential function of the form

$$f(x)=e^{x}$$

you can write it

$$f(x)=\exp(x)$$

which is really convenient when the power is a complex expression.

If you have a function that has a base other than $e$ is there a way to write it in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite $$a^x = {\rm e}^{x\ln(a)}=\exp(x\ln(a))$$